# Как можно использовать несколько классов php, которые наследуются от одного и того же класса, в одном файле php?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть класс DB, подключение к MySQL

Также есть 2 класса User и Post например, они наследуются от класса DB

Мне нужно в одном файле php использовать и класс User, и класс Post, и при подключении обоих классов появляется ошибка, что класс DB уже подключен, почему так происходит я понял, так как при подключении User класса, автоматом подключается и DB, а после попытки подключения Post, опять будет попытка подключения DB, использую require_once для подключения.

Comment: Ну ты тогда в классе Db отключайся после запроса и всё

Comment: Или используй одно соединение на всех (синглтон в помощь)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский у него там с инклудами проблема

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начать надо с того, что классы User и Post **не должны** наследоваться от DB. Ни пользователь,ни публикация не являются подключением к MySQL.

Они его только **используют**. И поэтому классы User и Post должны использовать класс DB, а не наследовать ему. Получая его экземпляр через конструктор.

и если на странице нужны объекты всех трех классов, то все  три и создать

```
$db = new DB();
$user = new User($db);
$post = new Post($db);
```

при этом никакое require_once для загрузки классов использоваться не должно, вместо этого должна использоваться **автозагрузка** классов.

Либо с помощью своей собственной функции, типа такой

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {
    $className = str_replace('\\', '/', $className);
    require __DIR__ . "/$className.php";
});
```

либо с помощью Композера

Comment: Спасибо большое за наводку, выручили